# Реализовать добавление данных в БД

Tags: php, mysql, telegram-bot, mysqli

Пишу телеграм-бота, который добавляет номера телефонов и проверяет наличие номеров в БД.
Сама функция добавления в БД написана, также реализована проверка номера в базе.

Возникла сложность с реализацией добавления номера в базу, поскольку используется одно регулярное выражение.

Может быть кто в курсе как решить эту задачу?
Код прилагаю.
Спасибо.

````
if ($text == "/start") {
    $reply = "Выберите действие: ";
    $reply_markup = $telegram->replyKeyboardMarkup(['keyboard' => $menu, 'resize_keyboard' => true,
        'one_time_keyboard' => false]);
    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply, 'reply_markup' => $reply_markup]);
} elseif ($text == "Внести в ЧС") {
    $reply = "Введите номер телефона без пробелов и дефисов в формате 7ХХХХХХХХХХ";
    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply]);
} elseif ($text == "Проверить") {
    $reply = "Для проверки ведите номер телефона без пробелов и дефисов в формате 7ХХХХХХХХХХ";
    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply]);
}  elseif (preg_match('#^([7][0-9]{10})$#', $text)) {
    $select_query = "SELECT * FROM textlog WHERE  text = '".$text."';";
    $select_query_result = mysqli_query($connect, $select_query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($select_query_result) > 0) {
    $reply = "Номер телефона находится в черном списке.";
    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply]);
    } else {
        $reply = "Введенный номер телефона в списке отсутствует!.";
        $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply]);
    }

}

else {
    $reply = "Введите корректный номер телефона.";
    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply]);
} ```
````

Comment: добавить номер в базу можно командой sql INSERT..

Comment: Это понятно, но дело в том, что и для проверки и для ввода используется одно регулярное выражение, и в логике кода при вводе номера для добавления срабатывает условие "Введенный номер телефона в списке отсутствует!."

Comment: значит логику перестрой

Comment: Благодарю за совет!

Comment: Регулярное выражение должно использоваться исключительно для проверки, что введённые данные соответствуют шаблону ввода, либо для нормализации введённых данных в шаблон. Проверка на дубликат и вообще запрет ввода дубликата реализуются путём создания уникального индекса, который не позволит создать запись с дубликатом, и отслеживания статуса операции добавления либо количества добавленных записей.

Comment: О, интересно!) Принял к сведению, буду переваривать..) Благодарю Вас!